# Seeking analytic form for integral exp(x -c/x) arising from an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I have been looking at a first order ordinary differential equation like

$$F_x(x) + F(x) = a + b\; \exp \left(\frac{-c}{x}\right)$$

and I can start to solve this using an integration factor of $e^x$ so that

$d(e^x F(x)) = e^x (a + b\; e^{\frac{-c}{x}}  ) dx$

giving me, with $k$ as a constant of integration,
$$ F(x) = e^{-x} a \int e^x \;dx\;  + b\; e^{-x} \int\exp \left(x -\frac{c}{x}\right)\; dx  \quad = \quad a + b \;e^{-x} \int \exp \left(x -\frac{c}{x}\right)\; dx \; + k$$
which helps but I am left with an integral I can't yet work out analytically, namely
$$\int \exp \left(x -\frac{c}{x}\right)\; dx $$

where $a,b$ are real and $c$ is real and positive and $0<x<\infty$.

Does anyone have any ideas how to integrate this exponential function of $x$ or otherwise solve the differential equation?    I have checked Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 8th ed,for clues in section 3.32-3.34, especially 3.324 and 3.471 and tried running it through Mathematica but without success.  It seems so innocent looking but has me scratching my head!

Comment: I do not think that there is an antiderivative. Just stay with the integrating factor.

Comment: Let $I(t)=\int\limits_0^t dx \ \exp(x-c/x)$. Expanding $e^x$, we find $I(t)=c\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c^n}{n!} \Gamma(-n-1,c/t)$. At leading order: $I(t) \sim c \Gamma(-1,c/t)$ for $t \to 0$. $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. Alternatively, we may integrate by parts to find $I(t) \sim c^{-1} t^2 \exp(t-c/t)$ for $t \to 0$ or $c \to \infty$, as well as $I(t) \sim \exp(t-c/t)$ for $t \to \infty$ or $c \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Expressing $\exp(x) $ as a series, taking its product with $\exp(-c/x)$ and integrating termwise gives
\begin{equation}
\int \exp \left(x -\frac{c}{x}\right) \; dx  \quad =  \quad
c\, \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{c}{x}\right) \underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{(-c)^n}{n! (n+1)!}\;+\;x\,\exp\left(-\frac{c}{x}\right) \underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\left(\frac{\underset{n=0}{\overset{m}{\sum }}(-c)^{m-n} \, x^n\, n!}{m! (m+1)!}\right)
\end{equation}
where $\text{Ei}(\cdot)$ is the Exponential Integral function
\begin{equation}
\text{Ei}(z) \equiv  -\int_{-z}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \; du \equiv  \int_{-\infty}^{z } \frac{e^{u}}{u} \; du.
\end{equation}

As a check I found that $\int_1^5 \exp\left( x - 0.2/x\right)\; dx =139.3487583860289 - 1.090680234718911 = 138.25807815131$  which compares well with Mathematica numerical integration of $138.2580781507764$.

This may have connections with the approach that @Sal mentions above, but I don't recognise whether the summations represent well known functions or not.  Any identification of these functions is welcome.